# Django Users, how can a user have permission to only edit the models they own (DRY)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, mixins

I am currently creating a lot of views and at each one of them only the User has permissions to access that view and create or edit the model.

Depending on the view I either put a small permission IF statement in the get_context_data or get_object.

While the following works I would like to make it more DRY since I have more than 20 views that need it:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SpaceCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        house = House.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        # CHECK IF USER HAS PERMISSION TO MAKE CHANGES TO THE MODEL
        if house.owner != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

or in the get_object() , and with more permission checks:

```
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(SpaceManage, self).get_object()
        house = House.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        space = Space.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['space_pk'])
        if space.house.owner != self.request.user and house.pk != space.house.pk:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return space
```

While I have read a lot on creating permissions ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication ), they seem to be applicable in cases where we want many users to have that permission instead of checking if the user has the permission to edit the models they have created.

Another possibility (in my opinion) is the use of mixins, but I don't seem to understand how they work and how to implement them.

**What I'm trying to achieve is:**

The user is only able to create, update and delete the models they have created, without re using the same code over and over in views.

**EDIT 1:** Based on @Lemayzeur's comments, creating a Mixin is the best approach for this. Any examples or explanations would be very helpful.

Comment: an approach is: create a decorator for those views

Comment: If you need per-object permission, consider checking out [Django guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) as Django does not support this out-of-the-box.

Comment: @lemayzeur correct me if i'm wrong but isn't using mixins on Class based views more flexible, extensible and DRYer?

Comment: Of course, they're much more *powerful*, *flexible* and allow for *DRYer* code.  With function based views, Django provides decorators to check for a specific stuff and for CBVs, it's not quite that simple. This means that you can apply decorator by overriding the dispatch method or by writing reusable class view decorator. But sometimes, you can get stuck when thinking about the functionality these decorators provide. **So writing these decorators as mixins instead makes them more flexible and DRYer**. This might be considered as a good one. ;-)

Comment: Thank you @lemayzeur ! do you have any references or examples that I can check?